# What has a chance of X to 21532020 (in base x+5) to happen?

Tags: probability

What has a chance of X to 21532020 (in base x+5) to happen?

what does it mean "a chance in base of"

that's the question nobody can solve it. I tried to ask my math teacher I tried google but no luck.

Comment: This isn't clear at all.

Comment: @lulu its math riddle but I need to know whats the chance in the base

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.   Suppose you replace the large number with a small one, like $30$ or $120$.  Can you work out whatever you are asking in that case?

Comment: @lulu im supposed to get some probability and then find something that has the same probability to happen but to get the probability I need to solve this. whats x to 21532020 in base x+5 but I don't know what kind of equation is that or what to search for

Comment: As I say, I have no idea at all what you are asking.  If you can't clarify the question, I think it should be closed.

Comment: If the $x$s are the same, there is either some obscure language/reference-based trick, or you have not represented the problem correctly. If $x=1$, odds of $1:649740$ would be meaningful ($649740$ is what you get when you read the number in base $6$). If $x=2$, odds of $2:1856673$ would make sense. etc. If the original problem was not in English, or might have had different words, please post the original.

Comment: @lulu this is all that was given to me.  This single line and I'm supposed  to solve it. Im as confused as you are

Comment: @MarkS. this is the original

Comment: Then it is nonsense or a weird non-math puzzle.

Comment: @MarkS. thx so much the correct answer was 1:659740 which is a probability of royal flush in poker and that was the answer

Comment: Then the English is still wrong: A royal flush has probability "1 **out of** 649740", but odds of "1 **to** 649739".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Assumptions:

1. The author of the problem doesn't care about the distinction between $X$ and $x$.
2. The author of the problem may be imprecise with wording about probability.
3. This is a riddle so requires some knowledge outside of math.

## Solution:

"$21532020$ (in base $x+5$)" likely refers to [number bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix). So we can [ask Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BFromDigits%5B%7B2%2C%201%2C%205%2C%203%2C%202%2C%200%2C%202%2C%200%7D%2C%205%20%2B%20x%5D%2C%20%7Bx%2C%201%2C%209%7D%5D) to convert the number into base $10$ for various values of $x$ with a command like `Table[FromDigits[{2, 1, 5, 3, 2, 0, 2, 0}, 5 + x], {x, 1, 9}]`, which gives numbers like $649740$, $1856673$ etc.

Given the assumptions, we get possible meanings for "a chance of X to 21532020 (in base x+5)" in a list like this:

- Probability $1$ out of $649740$
- Odds of $1$ to $649740$
- Probability $2$ out of $1856673$
- Odds of $2$ to $1856673$
- ...

Some people might recognize the first one as [the probability of a "royal flush" in poker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability#Frequency_of_5-card_poker_hands). So then the intended answer is most likely "A royal flush".